# Firebase FireStore complex security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

have one application where we have multiple `communities` and user that have roles to `write` message to it.
Each community has users under its own wing (`{communityId}/meta_users/{uid}`) I have written a function that access the roles under for user, I tried to go through the document but could not file any help.
I simulation I check that `userRoleLevel` will not allow to read even if the user has a role('admin') assigned to him.
please help me to correct it. I have pasted snippet of the rule below. let me know if need more info

```
function userRoleLevel(community){
  return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/communities/$(community)/meta_users/$(request.auth.uid)/roles/level)
  && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/communities/$(community)/meta_users/$(request.auth.uid)/roles/level).data.role;
}

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // All read is allowed for now.
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }


    match /communities/{community} {
      allow write: if owner();
      match /{category}/{message}{
       allow write: if loggedIn() 
       && (userRoleLevel(community) in ['owner', 'admin', 'writer']);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to this problem.
Thing is the location of the function it is outside the scope of the database schema and it is using segment variable for the database scope.

The solution is to move this function inside the database schema.

```
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        // All read is allowed for now.
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read;
        }
        // function should be located here <--------
        function userRoleLevel(community){
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/communities/$(community)/meta_users/$(request.auth.uid)/roles/level).data.role;
    }
...
}
```

Hope, this helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

You have the function `userRoleLevel()` returning a Boolean instead of a String containing the role. You won't be able to use `userRoleLevel(community) in ['owner', 'admin', 'writer']` unless you do the following.

```
function userRoleLevel(community){
  if( exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/communities/$(community)/meta_users/$(request.auth.uid)/roles/level) ) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/communities/$(community)/meta_users/$(request.auth.uid)/roles/level).data.role;
  } else {
    return false; // return something that won't match your roles
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not try it, but noticed the function returned a Boolean and you were checking for a String. The function I gave you will work if your firestore paths are correct.  You might need to pass &#39;request&#39; into userRoleLevel() as it may be out of the scope of the rule. Try logging it.